# corebluetooth : didDisconnectPeripheral reduce timeout

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

I am working with core bluetooth framework . I have implemented the **didDisconnectPeripheral** method to detect the disconnected peripheral . Right now it is calling around 20 seconds after peripheral has been disconnected . I want to reduce that timeout period . I have searched a lot in the document but not able to get the answer . is it really possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using that method, and it calls (nearly) immediately upon disconnection for me, so it definitely should be possible to reduce that delay period.  Are you sure you're not confusing that with the `didFailToConnectToPeripheral` method? The didFail method normally takes a long time to be called, because I believe I recall reading that Bluetooth LE doesn't have a timeout period, so it will try to connect for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have the delegate working on a background thread, which could explain the delay.

Check your initialization to see if it is going on the a different thread. If your queue value is something other than nil, that is likely the case.

```
self.centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
```

Also, in your `didDisconnectPeripheral` method, you can place this to determine if the thread changed when it was called.

```
NSLog(@"Current thread: %@",[NSThread currentThread]);
```

If the thread has changed, then you can modify the initialization to make sure it goes on the main.